# How do I fix my keyboard's unresponsiveness?

Tags: keyboard

I have recently purchased a new mechanical keyboard and during several gaming sessions, I have noticed that my keyboard's back light would turn off for a few milliseconds; along with my keys not functioning correctly. I also use a headset and each time this happens to my keyboard, my audio makes a snapping sound like it had been disconnected. Could it be the USB ports or is it the equipment itself? I have had no issues with my previous keyboard. This also happened only when I'm in game.

Comment: Mhh... how many USB devices are currently connected? Could be that there are simply to many, and your keyboard doesn't get enough juice (power is shared among connected devices). Try to disconnect a few USB devices and see if it works.

Comment: If you have a USB to PS2 adaptor, try running the keyboard using that (with no USB devices plugged into the keyboard) and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: I think the keyboard might be broken. You should try and return it to a new one and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: I agree with @5pike here. I actually had the same problem as you. I had my keyboard, mouse, headset, webcam, gamepad and minifridge (yes im that badass) connected at once. The keyboard would glitch out sometimes and that was pretty annoying.

Answer (score 3):

> Could it be the USB ports or is it the equipment itself?

Yes and yes.  Try these steps, in this order:

- Make sure the USB cable is plugged in firmly, both into the keyboard and into the computer.
- Remove other USB devices from the keyboard-hub, to eliminate the possibility of a power issue.
- Try a different USB port.  If it still happens, try other devices in those USB ports to make sure it's not an issue with your motherboard.
- Try a different USB cable.
- If none of the above work, the keyboard is likely defective.  RMA it to the manufacturer and get a different one.

Anecdotally:  I had a similar issue with a Rosewill mechanical keyboard *(which does not have any USB-out ports)*.  It turns out that, while the keys were built extremely well, the USB port on the keyboard was the flimsiest piece-of-crap you've ever seen.  I knew this already from reading the Newegg reviews when I bought it, which saved me a bunch of time when diagnosing the problem.  So the moral is, **check the Amazon/Newegg negative reviews to see if others are having similar issues**.